# SELECT permission was denied error message SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a user in SQL Server which uses SQL Server authentication.

I granted a select permission on views.

Everything was good until yesterday,But, today suddenly he received the below error.

> The SELECT permission was denied on the object

I have not changed anything. But, suddenly this error came up. How do I know what is the root cause of this?

Thanks,
Chakra

Comment: http://www.windowstechinfo.com/2014/09/solved-the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-home-add-database-myonttv-schema-dbo.html

Comment: extract and post the security DDL. Maybe he's not selecting from a view or maybe he's in a different database or maybe something changed that you don't know about